# how to speed up gazebo simulation?

Tags: ros, ros-control, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working with the [panda_gazebo](https://github.com/justagist/panda_simulator) package to control the 7-dofs franka manipulator, using the **cartesian velocity controller** of ros_control.
For computational constraints, I have to slow down the gazebo simulation, settting **real_time_update_rate** from 1000.0 to 100.0 and  **max_step_size** from 0.001 to 0.01. That's to keep a real time factor of 1.
Consequently, the PID controller frequency of the manipulator has been set from 1Khz to 100Hz.
The original PID values of the velocity controller working at 1Khz are as follows:

```
# Panda SDK Controllers: Velocity --------------------------  
velocity_joint_velocity_controller:                           
  type: panda_sim_controllers/PandaVelocityController         
  topic: /panda_simulator/motion_controller/arm/joint_commands
  joints:                                                     
    panda_joint1_controller:                                  
      joint: panda_joint1                                     
      pid: {p: 10,  i: 0.0, d: 0.1}                           
    panda_joint2_controller:                                  
      joint: panda_joint2                                     
      pid: {p: 100,  i: 1.0, d: 0.1}                          
    panda_joint3_controller:                                  
      joint: panda_joint3                                     
      pid: {p: 0.05,  i: 0.0, d: 0.01}                        
    panda_joint4_controller:                                  
      joint: panda_joint4                                     
      pid: {p: 0.5,  i: 0.01, d: 0.1}                         
    panda_joint5_controller:                                  
      joint: panda_joint5                                     
      pid: {p: 1.0,  i: 0.0, d: 0.01}                         
    panda_joint6_controller:                                  
      joint: panda_joint6                                     
      pid: {p: 0.05,  i: 0.0, d: 0.01}                        
    panda_joint7_controller:                                  
      joint: panda_joint7                                     
      pid: {p: 0.05,  i: 0.0, d: 0.01}
```

These parameters works fine for the simulation running at the 1Khz, but as soon as the frequency turns to 100Hz, I'm not able to control the manipulator anymore. Indeed, it starts moving randomly even when no commands are being sent at all.

I know a popular technique to manual tuning PID values is to increase Kp as much as possible, then working on Kd and finally Ki.
There is also a [pid_tuning](http://wiki.ros.org/pid_tuning) package available.

However, I wasn't  any luck with those approaches.

Knowing the correct parameters at 1Khz, I'm pretty sure there should be a rule of thumb to make those values work at 100Hz.
I've tried to just multiply/divide them by 10, since I'm now operating at 1/10th of the frequency, but again that approach failed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407262/how-to-speed-up-gazebo-simulation?/) by [underscoredavid](https://answers.ros.org/users/110617/underscoredavid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-10-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-10-01**:
The issue is you have created a bad physics simulation by making the time_step coarser. I doubt any amount of pid tuning is going to fix that.

**Comment by [underscoredavid](https://answers.ros.org/users/110617/underscoredavid/) on 2022-10-01**:
I reduced the timestamp because I need to work in real time but my machine doesn’t bear 1Khz. Are there other strategies to reduce the gazebo high-resource demanding or it’s a dead end project?

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-10-02**:
I edited your title to make it more general.

**Comment by [underscoredavid](https://answers.ros.org/users/110617/underscoredavid/) on 2022-10-10**:
Is there any tutorial explaining how to fix a broken gazebo simulation?

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-10-10**:
@underscoredavid Not that I'm aware of. It's a very difficult problem, because the input files are complex and there are so many possible configurations.

A common strategy is to start from a working simulation, and test each incremental change you make - that tends to help you narrow down where to look for the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, there are strategies to speed up the gazebo simulation. This is a general answer as I'm not familiar with your specific simulation:

- **never ever** use a mesh for collision geometry. This causes massive slowdown because each face has to be checked for collision. For a robot arm, you typically want to use a cylinder primitive for a link's collision geometry.
- reduce the number of "objects" in your world. They may look nice, but each one slows down the simulation.
- use `top` to make sure nothing else is using a significant amount of cpu on the host (the gazebo physics engine does not use multiple cpu cores, but you want to try to avoid pushing the cpu into thermal throttling.)
- run only the gazebo server, not the gazebo client (the GUI). If your host does not have a GPU with hardware OpenGL support, definitely do not run the GUI on the same machine.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1